# Adding a new statement each iteration of a for loop. Queue with 2d arrray

Tags: c++, iterator, queue, 2d

I am trying to create a stream of numbers through a 2d array kind of like a queue but over 2 dimensions.

The final function will take std::string.

I have written some pretty horrific code.. eventually. I looked for a pattern but the thing that gets me is each time the number moves down the queue it needs another line of code and it has to move into the next element in the array.

I figure once I can do that I can put it in a loop.

so you basically add another line of code each time it adds a new number from the iterator.

```
intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];

    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][2] = intarray[0][1];
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];

    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][3] = intarray[0][2];
    intarray[0][2] = intarray[0][1];
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];

    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][4] = intarray[0][3];
    intarray[0][3] = intarray[0][2];
    intarray[0][2] = intarray[0][1];
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];

    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][5] = intarray[0][4];
    intarray[0][4] = intarray[0][3];
    intarray[0][3] = intarray[0][2];
    intarray[0][2] = intarray[0][1];
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];

    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    intarray[0][6] = intarray[0][5];
    intarray[0][5] = intarray[0][4];
    intarray[0][4] = intarray[0][3];
    intarray[0][3] = intarray[0][2];
    intarray[0][2] = intarray[0][1];
    intarray[0][1] = intarray[0][0];
```

[the numbers go down each time a new number is added from the iterator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXm2Z.png)

Comment: You might be interested to learn about the [`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) function.

Comment: Anytime you find yourself writing a bunch of lines which are almost identical except for one or two indices, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. You should try using a loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, that would have worked well, however, the final function will move string types, I let that out of the question, apologies. is the answer to copy into an empty array move one position then copy back?

Comment: When you say "string type", do you mean `std::string`? Then perhaps [`std::copy_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) instead?

Comment: Yea it will be a std::string. I will check the function out and report back! @BessieTheCow a loop you say?! How would you suggest to work a loop in? I have tried but it needs another line from my limited knowledge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these nested loops is what you need

```
auto jj = 1u;
while (!condition)
{
    intarray[0][0] = *it;
    ++it;
    for (auto ii=jj; ii >= 1 ; --ii)
        intarray[0][ii] = intarray[0][ii-1];
    ++jj;
}
```

where `condition` is whatever condition when you need to stop the process.
This code is not very efficient, though.

---

**EDIT**
As I understand you need to use both dimensions, so you have options:

**a)** if you know the size of your data beforehand, and I think it is the case, since you use statically allocated `intarray[N][M]`:

```
for (auto kk=N-1; 0 <= kk; --kk)
    for (auto ii=M-1; 0 <= ii ; --ii)
        {
            intarray[kk][ii] = *it;
            ++it;
        }
```

you simply fill the array in reverse order, and there is no need to overwrite values many times.

**b)** if you don't know the size beforehand, but have enough memory (and time):
populate dynamically-sized container (I'd recommend `std::vector<int>`) with data and go route a)

**c)** if you don't know the size beforehand and don't have enough memory to hold temporary container, you are not able to use statically allocated array. The only solution I see is to populate an `std::vector<T>` with data, and then write a wrapper function to get the elements in right order.

---

**EDIT2:**
According to the image you posted in the commentary, you need simple wrapper around an array. Disclaimer: I have not tested the code below, nevertheless, it should work, maybe after minor tweaks.

```
//while you can do it without class, I prefer this way
class MyArray
{
public:
    //push value in the array
    void push_back(const int a)
    {
        //move values using std::memmove as suggested above 
        std::memmove(&(arr[1]),&(arr[0]),2*N - 1);
        //store first element
        arr[0]=a;
    }

    //calculate index in array and return
    int at(const int a, const int b)
    {
        if (0 == a) //first row
            return arr.at(b); //return just the index
        if (1 == a) //second row
            return arr.at(N - 1 - b); //if 
    }
private:
    //dimension of the array
    static const int N = 10;
    //contiguous static array is enough here
    //one can use C-style array, but no point for doing so
    std::array<int, 2*N> arr;
}

//usage
MyArray mArr;

while(!condition)
{
    mArr.push_back(*it);
    std::cout<<mArr.at(1,2)<<std::endl;
}
```

To 'move the queue' it is handy to use `std::memmove`, as suggested by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836798/adding-a-new-statement-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop-queue-with-2d-arrray/60840012?noredirect=1#comment107636132_60836798). Since `std::memmove` operates over contiguous memory, use `std::array`, `std::vector` or 1D C-style array instead of 2D C-style array to hold all elements. To get values calculate the right index for it, depending on the row (first or second).

Comment: This works for one dimension when the loop gets to intarray[0][9] whatever is in that element should move to intarray[1][0] and the process should continue.

I've added a couple of conditional statements but I am sure there is a cleaner way?

Comment: Could you please provide expected input coming from `iteraror it` and expected output? Do I understand right that you want fill some 2d array in reverse order?

Comment: the final program will take the document file paths in std::string format the iterator will be provided with a std::list of filepaths, the function above will pull the contents of the list through the 2d array from [0][0] to [0][9] 

then [0][9] will then move to [1][0]

what is in [1][0] will move to [1][1] and so on until it gets to [1][9].

Comment: The array size is fixed at 2x10. this is for a picture viewer on an application the images should scroll through the array in the fashion in this imag

https://i.ibb.co/vBp72Hr/array.png

as one image comes into an array the last image pops out it should function like a 2D std:queue..

apologies for not including this information!

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully it is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210319/discussion-between-tam-and-suthiro).

Comment: so it turns out that the nested loops from the first question were what I needed however now I am trying to get it to pass through the opposite way, I have tried adjusting the nested loops but have not been able to reach a solution. how am I able to edit the loops to try make it work from element [2][10] and push the iterator from that end?

Comment: @Tam could you please start a new question containing next information: the question itself; the code you currently use; what are you trying to achieve (the image as in previous time would be perfect; what you've already tried. Also, if my answer to this question was what you needed, please mark it as 'accepted'. Thanks.